# How to let mpdf php pdf library support css3, i mean all modern browser css

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, mpdf

i am generating pdf using php and mpdf.

can anyone tell me how to let css3 support all css in mpdf

for example :display inline-block dosent support in mpdf and webkit skew..

How to let mpdf library support all css3 css

```
include_once('mpdf/mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/stylesheet.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$html = $_POST['shelf'];
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output('installation.pdf', D);
exit;
```

Comment: The library should be updated by the creators/contributors. I've been using mpdf also and all the available CSS should be enough to make nice PDF creations. Try to work with what you do have from the library and not what you do not have.